# Add values later to a constant-Array

Tags: php

Is there a possibility to add on an existing constant-array some values?

```
define("USERID", array(123));
```

I've tried with

```
define("USERID", '456');
```

And google didn't get an answer as well,-)

Comment: Constants are constant, so if the value isn't constant don't use a constant.

Comment: If you could, the syntax would be `USERID[1] = 456;`

Answer (score 0):

From : http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

> A constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. As the name
>   suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script

Comment: Thanks, everything clear now!  by the way, my thoughts was to use a constants instead of a session var. Good idea?

Comment: @StillerEugen use `$_SESSION`, that way if you do need to change a value it caries over to the next page load

Answer (score 0):

You might have tried this:

```
define('USERID', [123, 456]);
```

But that won't work, defining a constant a second time is simply ignored by php and keeps the first value it was defined as.

Instead you might consider using a static class variable. Or even a public property or getter method for a class. Or just a global variable.